# Accessing R list elements through function parameters

Tags: list, r, syntax

I have an R list which looks as follows

```
> str(prices)
List of 4
 $ ID   : int 102894616
 $ delay: int 8
 $ 47973      :List of 12
  ..$ id       : int 47973
  ..$ index        : int 2
  ..$ matched: num 5817
 $ 47972      :List of 12
..
```

Clearly, I can access any element by e.g. prices$"47973"$id.

However, how would I write a function which parametrises the access to that list? For example an access function with signature:

```
access <- function(index1, index2) { .. }
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
> access("47973", "matched")
5817
```

This seems very trivial but I fail to write such a function. Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `'[['` instead of `'$'` seems to work:

```
prices <- list(
    `47973` = list( id = 1, matched = 2))

access <- function(index1, index2) prices[[index1]][[index2]]
access("47973","matched")
```

---

As to why this works instead of:
`access <- function(index1, index2) prices$index1$index2` (which I assume is what you tried?) it's because here `index1` and `index2` are not evaluated. That is, it searches the list for an element called `index1` instead of what this object evaluates to.

Comment: Excellent, I was beginning to think there was no way around this.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of the fact that `[[` accepts a vector, used recursively:

```
prices <- list(
    `47973` = list( id = 1, matched = 2))

prices[[c("47973", "matched")]]
# 2
```