# How to use a string variable to select a data frame column using $ notation

Tags: r, dataframe

From the reading I've been doing with R, I can select a column in a data frame by either of these two methods:  `frame[,column]` or `frame$column`.  However, when I have a string as a variable, it works only in the first.  In other words, consider the following:

I have a data frame, tmp, a subset of a larger data frame of question responses.  V1 is the responder's id, Q5.3 is the response, a 1 or 0:

```
            V1 Q5.3
2 R_bdyKkzWcvBxDFTT    1
3 R_41wnKUQcM8mUW2x    0
4 R_2ogeykkgbH2e4RL    1
5 R_8D4jzMBfYO0M0ux    1
6 R_3KPgP2pxWROnip7    1

str(tmp)

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ V1  : Factor w/ 364 levels "R_0039orNoOoWaDQx",..: 256 116 70 201 95
     $ Q5.3: num  1 0 1 1 1
```

Now, I define a variable x, that holds the string of the name of one of the columns.

```
x<-"Q5.3"
```

tmp[,x] returns what I think it should return:

```
tmp[,x]

[1] 1 0 1 1 1
```

tmp$"Q5.3" returns what I think it should return:

```
tmp$"Q5.3"

[1] 1 0 1 1 1
```

tmp$x however returns

```
tmp$x

NULL
```

How can I tell R to interpret tmp$x as tmp$"Q5.3".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have a variable `x` with a column name in `tmp`, `tmp[,x]` or `tmp[[x]]` are the correct ways to extract it. You cannot get R to treat `tmp$x` as `tmp$"Q5.3"`. `tmp$x` will always refer to the item named "x" in "tmp".

Comment: this has got to be a dupe ...

Comment: @BenBolker I can never find a good dup for this question even though it comes up soooooo often. I was thinking of starting one. "What's the difference between $, [], and [[]] when working with data.frames?"

Comment: Do you know where this is discussed in any documentation?  I couldn't find it anywhere, and have wasted a bit of time trying things like parse() and such...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242598/accessing-r-list-elements-through-function-parameters

Comment: @WilliamOliver it's talked about in the ?"$" help page but it's not super clear i will admit. If you search for "One common mistake" on this page http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html you will get an overview of the issue.

Comment: Thx.  I'm not surprised that browsing the questions didn't turn it up.

Comment: @MrFlick -- That's a great page.  Thanks.

Comment: @BenBolker That's not bad, but it's certainly not as direct as I would like it to be. I can't blame others for not understanding what's going on there. I'd like something more like the link i shared above.

Comment: Not related to this but canonical for `[` vs. `[[`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the/1169495#1169495

Comment: I'm sure there are more out there, but `$` is hard to search for.

Comment: @BenBolker Here are a couple,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730806/r-access-data-frame-column-using-variable,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-specific-column-using-the-dollar-sign-in-r.  The latter seems to have more closed questions pointing to it.

Comment: @GSee Thanks for those pointers, the explanation at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-specific-column-using-the-dollar-sign-in-r was great