# R - Aggregate data with variable name using dcast

Tags: r, reshape2

`Python` guy new to `R`, so forgive the naive question.

I have an `R` dataframe named `metrics` with four columns:

I want to pass the level of aggregation (`day` or `week`) as a variable to `dcast` for aggregation.

`agg_level <- c("week")`

If I hard-code `week` in the in the function, it aggregates data for each week correctly:

- `met <- dcast(metrics, week ~ city, value.var = count, fun.aggregate = sum)`
- Output:

`week`    `NYC`    `CHI` `SF`

`2015-10-18` `1` `2` `3`

`2015-10-25` `4` `5` `6`

If I replace `week` with the variable, it fails. (It aggregates data for ***all*** weeks.)

- `met <- dcast(metrics, agg_level ~ city, value.var = count, fun.aggregate = sum)`
- Output:

`agg_level`    `NYC`    `CHI` `SF`

`week` `5` `7` `9`

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717397/r-how-use-a-string-variable-to-select-a-data-frame-column-using-notation), `metrics[[agg_level]]` extracts a column from variable, but this fails:

- `met <- dcast(m, [[agg_level]] ~ city, value.var = metric, fun.aggregate = sum)`
- `Error in (function ... unexpected '[['`

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you show a reproducible example

Comment: Added example correct output, and the output I get when passing variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula argument of dcast expects that the words passed to it are column/variable names inside of the data.frame x.  It does not recognize or resolve the fact that "agg_level" is a variable.  As such, you have two options:

```
# Option 1
# Do some text operations to make the formula based on variables.
if(this==that) {agg_level <- 'week'} else {agg_level <- 'day'}
myFormula <- sprintf("%s ~ city", agg_level)
met <- dcast(metrics, as.formula(myFormula), sum, value.var = metric)

# Option 2 - Untested
# Take advantage of dcast's alternative to the formula notation and pass a list instead.
# No idea if this will work.
met <- dcast(metrics, list(.(agg_level),.(city)), sum, value.var=metric)
```

Comment: #2 error: `Error in inherits(x, "formula") : could not find function "."`

Comment: #1 resolution: 

`met <- dcast(metrics, as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ city", agg_level)), sum, value.var = metric)`

Comment: Figures... I'm not going to bother tracing that down.  You should also look into dplyr, it's a lot faster than plyr and is intended to operate via pipelines, which might be a bit more familiar for you, coming from Python.

Comment: Also, I just saw your combining of dcast, as.formula, and sprintf into a one-liner.  Yes, it's more compact.  However, there are cases where in R where doing multiple operations in a single line is actually slower than doing them all seperately.  Weird, I know, but that's R for you.

Comment: Thanks. Ya, I've been looking at `dplyr `. Nice package. FWIW, `dcast` is from `reshape` library; interested if `dplyr` has function similar to `dcast` ... Will look into that.

Comment: Ah. Good to know about splitting operations into multiple lines :)

Comment: It doesn't exactly. It's a bit more close to working in something like SQL. An equivalent would use both `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages: `met <- metrics %>% group_by(week, city) %>% summarize(metric=sum(metric)) %>% spread(city, metric)`

Comment: Nice. Just got `tidyr `. May change the logic, as you suggest, depending on performance.