# How can I dynamically refer to an attribute in an R data frame?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` named `df` with a number of attributes. These attributes represent the permutations of three dimensions:

- `dim1`
- `dim2`
- `dim3`

The attributes thus are:

- `df$dim1a.dim2a.dim3a`
- `df$dim1a.dim2a.dim3b`
- `df$dim1a.dim2b.dim3a`
- ...
- `df$dim1b.dim2a.dim3a`
- `df$dim1b.dim2a.dim3b`
- ...
- `df$dim1n.dim2n.dim3n`

I am now trying to make my data accessible in Shiny, where I offer a widget item for each dimensions that allows the user select one value for that dimension. If the user selects

- `dim1a`
- `dim2c`
- `dim3b`

I want to display data for `df$dim1a.dim2c.dim3b`.

**How can I dynamically access the part of the data frame that the user is asking to have displayed?**

I can construct the name of the attribute by constructing it via

```
display_data <- paste0(input$radioButton_dim1,'.',input$radioButton_dim2,'.',input$radioButton_dim3)
```

But how can I refer to it when trying to select it from the df or subset the data frame to select the data?

+++ Update:

When I try subsetting the data frame by using `df[,display_data]`, the objects of class "Lines" are being returned. If I just use `df$dim1a.dim2c.dim3b`, I get a list of the actual attribute values for those objects, which is what I am looking for.

+++

If this is not easily feasible or not recommended for some reason, can something like melting/casting also be performed on a SpatialLinesDataFrame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R how use a string variable to select a data frame column using $ notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717397/r-how-use-a-string-variable-to-select-a-data-frame-column-using-notation)

Comment: Thanks @CL. for pointing this out. I had already played with the (single) bracket notation to no avail. I will gp through all suggestions made in the referenced post (and references therein) and update my question.

Comment: I don't now if there is something special about `SpatialLinesDataFrame` (as compared to a normal `data.frame`), but a simple `df[, display_data]` should give you the column indicated by the value of `display_data`.

Comment: SpatialLinesDataFrames are not really dataframes but rather S4 objects, needing different accessor functions.

Comment: I updated my OP. I do not get the same results from using bracket notation as when referring to the attribute wit df$... Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example that generates a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` along with a possilbe selector?