# How to call an vector inside a list without explicitly referencing object's name?

Tags: r

I have a list mylist and I know how to call one of its object by its name

```
head(mylist$"26533")
[1] 39.67125 33.33558 33.75013 51.71748 47.86691 35.98055
```

But when I try to get the same result with using x,

```
x <- "26533"
head(mylist$x)
```

R tells me the result is NULL.
Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select a data frame column using $ and the name of the column as a string in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-data-frame-column-using-and-the-name-of-the-column-as-a-string-in-a-v) and another [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717397/r-how-use-a-string-variable-to-select-a-data-frame-column-using-notation)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

We can use `[[` to pass a variable to extract the `list` element

```
mylist[[x]]
```

If there are multiple elements in 'x', use `[`

```
mylist[x]
```

Comment: Maybe because for some users "Do not downvote a valid answer rule" is becoming less relevant after seeing your mountain of answers on duplicated posts. Please make an effort to find duplicate target post before posting an answer.

Comment: @akrun as I said before, don't ask this question. I would like to keep my choices to myself.