# How to Refer to Column Name in Shiny and Leaflet

Tags: r, function, shiny, leaflet

I am referring to the choropleth tutorial for Leaflet (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/choropleths.html) and modifying it for Shiny. I have different columns that I want to be able to use depending on what the user selects. The problem I encounter has to do with this part:

```
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = states$density, bins = bins)

m %>% addPolygons(
  fillColor = ~pal(density),
  weight = 2,
  opacity = 1,
  color = "white",
  dashArray = "3",
  fillOpacity = 0.7)
```

Specifically, I want to be able to replace the `density` column be a column that I can get from a button in Shiny (assume the columns are called `a` and `b` and that I get them from the `name_button` object). I create the `col_name` function to enclose this choice:

```
col_name <- reactive({
  name <- switch(input$name_button, "A" = "a", "B" = "b" )
  name})
```

Then I can modify the `pal <- ...` line as follows (see [R how use a string variable to select a data frame column using $ notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717397/r-how-use-a-string-variable-to-select-a-data-frame-column-using-notation?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = states[[col_name()]], bins = bins)
```

However, I am not sure how to change the `fillColor = ~pal(density),` line because `density` is the name of a column. I have tried

```
fillColor = ~pal([[col_name]])
```

but this doesn't work. What can I do?

Also, what is the function of the tilde `~` in `~pal(...)`?

Comment: Try this: `fillColor = ~ pal(states[[col_name]])`? For the tilde sign, maybe you can read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14976331/use-of-tilde-in-r-programming-language)? I think for `~ pal(density)`, `pal()` is a function that takes the number (density) and returns a color index.

Comment: This works. The only change (and I should have done this too) is to add `()` after `col_name` because it is a function: `fillColor = ~ pal(states[[col_name()]])`. But the key point of having `states` in front holds. Thanks for the help!